# Labeling rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, rows

I have this code

```
SELECT date(start_date) FROM `project` 
WHERE name = "Project_A"
UNION
SELECT date(end_date) FROM `project` 
WHERE name = "Project_A"
```

and the result is

```
1/2/2013
5/3/2014
```

What I want to happen is have kind of like a label for the date, the result I want is

```
Start | 1/2/2013
End   | 5/3/2014
```

i just want to have a label for the two rows, how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do something like this:

```
SELECT 'START', date(start_date) FROM `project` 
WHERE name = "Project_A"
UNION
SELECT 'END', date(end_date) FROM `project` 
WHERE name = "Project_A"
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! i'm trying to accept your answer but says i need to wait for 9 minutes. anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Solid answer. I was using another view with my label before hand and joining without condition. This is fare nicer and requires no views.